# UI is not updated when OnEvent is being called in Android Event Bus

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

Here I used `@Subscribe` annotation but my **calender_text** is not updated.But  `calender_text.setText("Test")`  properly working in side the oncreate method.What can be the issue?

```
  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onEvent(Date event) {

        // your implementation
        date = event.getSelected_date();
        calender_text.setText("Test");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.getSelected_date(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Is the toast being displayed?

Comment: Yes.It is displaying.

Comment: @HRCJ Did you check the logcat for any warning messages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register EventBus in `onStart()` method

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }
```

You need to unregister EventBus in `onStop()` method

```
 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```